# UITableView swipe left to right

Tags: ios, uitableview

Is there an implementation for left-to-right swiping on `UITableViewCell`s that is default in iOS/CocoaTouch? Or do I need a library?

Just like the default mail app on iOS (mark as read).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of iOS 8.2, you still need third party code to do this.

You can use [MCSwipeTableViewCell](https://github.com/alikaragoz/MCSwipeTableViewCell) for example. It has a lot of features, and is well maintained on GitHub.

Comment: Nice edit! ;) This is actually sad that it isn't standard in iOS. I will be using [this framework](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell), even though the link you provided has more features (swipe through), but I don't need those and this one seems to be updated more quickly.

Comment: Yep, this one is also great. I've tried it as well.