# Adding action when swiping right on UITABLEVIEW in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a regular uitableview setup with and currently when a user swipes left, the action appears. I want to add an action when a user swipes right but I cannot find anywhere in Apple documentation or online on how to do this. Any thoughts?

Here is my current setup:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return expandedIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) ? 200.0 : 50.0

}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    // the cells you would like the actions to appear needs to be editable
    return true
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {



}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {


    let share = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Done") { action, index in



        let currentElement = self.tipArray[indexPath.row]

        let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate


        let context: NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext

        var ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Tips", inManagedObjectContext: context)

        self.repurposeManagedObjectContext("Tips", forAttribute: "rowNumber", object: indexPath.row)


        self.tipArray.insert(currentElement, atIndex: self.tipArray.count)
        self.tipArray.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }

   // let categorize = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle, title: <#T##String?#>, handler: <#T##(UITableViewRowAction, NSIndexPath) -> Void#>)
    share.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

    return [share]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options.

You can use a [third-party library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28990860/2518285).

Or you can roll your own solution [using gesture recognisers](http://belencruz.com/2015/03/swipe-gestures-in-a-uitableview/).